# Missing Intellisense in VS 2015 RC for Xaml

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015

Having been quite spoilt by [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/92dd9bfb-6b79-40eb-8f31-0dbfa054fc24) excellent add on for VS 2013, it has come of something of a shock to find that there is absolutely no Xaml intellisense when using vs 2015 RC.

in the options I have made sure that it is selected:

[image]

and that the designer is used as the default when editing my views;

[image]

I have started and restarted Visual Studio several times and yet intellisense remains stubbornly inactive when creating Xaml ( NB it is fine when writing either VB or C# code).

Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution?. Visual Studio 2013 is still on my machine, but the two should work happily side by side, indeed my experience is that they do bar this little matter of no intellisense for xaml.

Thanks

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: @rleffler  I ended up speaking with Microsoft about this.  On a clean machine running just vs2015rc and working with new projects I get intellisense.  Projects from another machine originally developed in vs2013 generally (but not always) fail to display it.  On a machine where vs2013 and 2015rc co-exist intellisense in xaml in 2015 only works in new projects.  The current suggestion (which I have yet to try) is to reset the vs settings file(TOOLS->Options->Import and Export Settings). Will keep you posted if this works.

Comment: thanks for the update.  I have a new install of 2015rc and its still not giving it to me.  I will mess around with more settings and let you know if i find anything as well.

Comment: Dom, your suggestion solved the problem

Answer (score 8):

Uncheck **Enable XAML designer**, restart VS; then check **Enable XAML designer** again and restart VS again, the Intellisense comes out. This works for me. :)

Comment: But it wasn't enough for me, mine started working after doing those steps and building the project

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced this and my solution was to reset the environment settings using the Import and Export Wizard.  Tools->Import and Export Settings. And then clicking on "Reset all settings".

Comment: Tried that several times, unfortunately it's yet to make a difference.

Comment: Actually had this problem with Blend 2015 and this fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the .suo file and restarting Visual Studio (20015 rc) solved this for me.